# return the mapped object if expression inside of purrr:possibly() fails

Tags: r, error-handling, purrr

I have a data frame, one column of which contains more data frames. One of those data frames is missing a column. I would like to remove that column from the other two data frames, if it exists.

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
nest -> tmp
tmp[3,'data'][[1]][[1]] <- dplyr::select(tmp[3,'data'][[1]][[1]], -mpg)

print(tmp)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>     cyl data              
>   <dbl> <list>            
> 1    6. <tibble [7 × 10]> 
> 2    4. <tibble [11 × 10]>
> 3    8. <tibble [14 × 9]>
> ```

So here, the `data` column contains three tibbles, the last of which doesn't contain the column `mpg`. I can map dplyr::select over the data column, and catch errors by returning `NA` as follows:

```
 tmp %>% mutate(data2 = map(data, possibly(~dplyr::select(.,-mpg), otherwise = NA)))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>     cyl data               data2            
>   <dbl> <list>             <list>           
> 1    6. <tibble [7 × 10]>  <tibble [7 × 9]> 
> 2    4. <tibble [11 × 10]> <tibble [11 × 9]>
> 3    8. <tibble [14 × 9]>  <lgl [1]>
> ```

But what I'd really rather do is return the input data. Something like:

```
 tmp %>% mutate(data2 = map(data, possibly(~dplyr::select(.,-mpg), otherwise = function(x){x})))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>     cyl data               data2            
>   <dbl> <list>             <list>           
> 1    6. <tibble [7 × 10]>  <tibble [7 × 9]> 
> 2    4. <tibble [11 × 10]> <tibble [11 × 9]>
> 3    8. <tibble [14 × 9]>  <fn>
> ```

But of course this just returns `function(x){x}` as the last row of `data2`.

Any clever ideas? Or is this the kind of situation where I just need to use `tryCatch` or otherwise handle errors more explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `otherwise` argument in `possibly` is a constant, so it can't change with the input of the wrapped function; What you might do is wrap `possibly` in another function that can access element from `data`, set the element as `otherwise`:

```
my_select <- function(x) {
    f = possibly(function() select(x, -mpg), otherwise = x)
    f()
}

tmp %>% mutate(data2 = map(data, my_select))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl data               data2            
#  <dbl> <list>             <list>           
#1  6.00 <tibble [7 x 10]>  <tibble [7 x 9]> 
#2  4.00 <tibble [11 x 10]> <tibble [11 x 9]>
#3  8.00 <tibble [14 x 9]>  <tibble [14 x 9]>
```

Or take the formula form:

```
tmp %>% 
    mutate(data2 = map(data, ~ (invoke(possibly(function() select(.,-mpg), otherwise = .)))))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl data               data2            
#  <dbl> <list>             <list>           
#1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <tibble [7 × 9]> 
#2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <tibble [11 × 9]>
#3     8 <tibble [14 × 9]>  <tibble [14 × 9]>
```

Comment: Thanks! The first version works for me and so I am accepting this solution. In the second "formula form" version though I notice that in both your example and when I run on my computer the first two elements of `data2` still have width of 10 and if I drill down into the output, I see that this is because the `mpg` column is still there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I missed the part. It seems the nested `formula` caused the problem. Change the inner formula to a normal anonymous function solved the issue.